# Delete causes memory error with virtual destructor in base class

Tags: c++, pointers, delete-operator, virtual-destructor

I don't really understand why I get bad function call here:

```
Event* e = *(it->second.begin());
callbackBindings[it->first](e);
delete e;
```

`e` is an instance of an object derived from `Event`. `Event` has a public virtual destructor. My derived class has an empty, but implemented destructor. `delete e` gives me a memory error here. Why? (`e` is a valid pointer)

edit: full code, maybe it helps:

```
#include "EventHandler.h"
std::unordered_map<std::type_index, std::function<void(Event*)>> EventHandler::callbackBindings = std::unordered_map<std::type_index, std::function<void(Event*)>>();
std::unordered_map<std::type_index, std::list<Event*>> EventHandler::eventList = std::unordered_map<std::type_index, std::list<Event*>>();
void EventHandler::Update()
{
    auto it = eventList.begin();
    while(it != eventList.end())
    {
        if(it->second.size() < 1) //erase empty event lists!
        {
            eventList.erase(it++);
        }
        else
        {

            if(callbackBindings.count(it->first) < 0) //erase events without listener!
            {
                //delete all messages
                auto eventIt = it->second.begin();
                while(eventIt != it->second.end())
                {
                    Event* e = *(eventIt++);
                    delete e;
                }
                //remove list entry
                eventList.erase(it++);
            }
            else //perform callback
            {
                auto eventIt = it->second.begin();
                while(eventIt != it->second.end())
                {
                    //dereference iterator for ease of use & iterate
                    Event* e = *(eventIt++);
                    //callback function
                    callbackBindings[it->first](e);
                    //remove event from list
                    it->second.remove(e); //with a single message, this is where it crashes!
                    //delete event
                    delete e;
                }
                ++it;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

## EDIT:

Okay, the error seems to be somewhere else. When I comment out

```
callbackBindings[it->first](e);
```

It won't crash ?!

## Edit: Oh my error is somewhere else!

The following function is supposed to put an object into a map, indexed by its type:

```
static void DispatchEvent(Event* e)
    {
        //te.event = e;
        auto index = std::type_index(typeid(&e));
        //eventList.push_back(te);
        if(eventList.count(index) < 1)
        {
            eventList[index] = std::list<Event*>();
        }
        eventList[index].push_back(e);
    }
```

unfortunately the type is ALWAYS Event, but what I need is the derived type of the object (LogEvent in this case, which is derived from Event). Do I need to make this a template function or is there a way to get the ACTUAL type of an object, no matter what it has been cast to?

Comment: Probably memory corruption in code you haven't shown. Can you provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: "Event has a public virtual destructor." - I hope it's not pure virtual destrcutor?

Comment: I don't think it's pure:
    public:
       virtual ~Event() {};

Comment: in callbackBindings[it->first](e); did you check that it-> first is a valid index and that callbackBindings[it->first] isn't a null pointer?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get your desired `type_index` key, you must use `typeid()` with a reference or dereferenced pointer, as e.g. [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/fyf39xec.aspx) or [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) nicely document.

So change the line creating the type_index to:

```
std::type_index index = typeid(*e);
```

or

```
auto index = std::type_index(typeid(*e));
```

I believe the first version to be clearer.